# Android 2.2 EditText.setText(..) does not change the text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-2.2-froyo, settext

Alright, I'm at my wits end.
**What I am doing:**
 - GET an xml
 - Parse xml
 - Load layouts (EditText boxes) depending on the parsed-xml (through a wrapper class with kay/value stuff)
 - saving the xml in onSaveInstanceState
 - saving the EditText boxes content (getting the key/value-pairs) in onSaveInstanceState
 - --> *rotating the screen manually*
 - loading the xml and parsing it again
 - getting the key/value pairs of the EditText boxes depending on the keys of the newly generated EditText boxes

**What I am trying to do:**
 - setting the text of the new EditText boxes with the old content (depending on the keys)

**Problem**
 - the text is not set

**Code**
MyActivity.class

```
    private String commentRequestResult = "";
    private CommentSectionComponent commentSectionComponent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        publicationId = intent.getStringExtra(ExtraKeyProvider.PUBLICATION_ID);
        ...
        try {
            if (savedInstanceState != null && ActivityStackHelper.isCalledInSuccession(this)) {
                ...
                commentRequestResult = savedInstanceState.getString(BundleKeyProvider.PUBLICATIONS_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_COMMENTS);
                createCommentsSection(commentRequestResult, savedInstanceState);
            } else {
                ...
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Message.show(e);
        }
    }

    private void createCommentsSection(String internalRequestResult, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        XmlParser parser = new XmlParser(internalRequestResult);

        commentSectionComponent = new CommentSectionComponent(this);

        BaseCommentComponent newCommentComponent = getNewCommentComponent();
        commentSectionComponent.addCommentComponent(newCommentComponent);

        ...
        fillCommentSectionFromSavedInstance(savedInstanceState);
    }

        private void fillCommentSectionFromSavedInstance(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                System.out.println("restoring...");
                String lastSelectedKey = BundleKeyProvider.PUBLICATIONS_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_COMMENTS_LAST_FOCUS;
                String lastSelected = savedInstanceState.getString(lastSelectedKey);

                List<BaseCommentComponent> baseCommentComponents = commentSectionComponent.getBaseCommentComponents();
                for (BaseCommentComponent baseCommentComponent : baseCommentComponents) {
                    Comment comment = baseCommentComponent.getComment();
                    baseCommentComponent.openCommentForWriting();
                    baseCommentComponent.setText("DOES NOT WORK");
//getting the EditText from baseCommentComponent does also not help
                }
            }
        }
```

BaseCommentComponent

```
public abstract class BaseCommentComponent {

    protected LinearLayout currentLinearLayout;
    protected Context context;
    protected Request request;
    private Button sendButton;
    protected Button abortButton;
    private final EditText textField;
    private final EditText nameTextField;
    private Comment comment;

    public BaseCommentComponent(LinearLayout currentLinearLayout, Comment comment, Context context, Request request, Button sendButton, Button abortButton, EditText textField,
            EditText nameTextField) {
        this.currentLinearLayout = currentLinearLayout;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.context = context;
        this.request = request;

        this.sendButton = sendButton;
        this.abortButton = abortButton;
        this.textField = textField;
        this.nameTextField = nameTextField;
        OnClickListener abortListener = getAbortButtonListener(sendButton, abortButton, textField, nameTextField);
        this.abortButton.setOnClickListener(abortListener);
        OnClickListener replyButtonClickedListener = getInitialButtonListener();
        this.sendButton.setOnClickListener(replyButtonClickedListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener getInitialButtonListener() {
        System.out.println("getInitialButtonListener");
        OnClickListener replyButtonClickedListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                openCommentForWriting();
                sendButton.setOnClickListener(getSendButtonClickedListener());
            }

        };
        return replyButtonClickedListener;
    }

    public void openCommentForWriting() {
        System.out.println("openCommentForWriting");
        textField.setVisibility(EditText.VISIBLE);
        nameTextField.setVisibility(EditText.VISIBLE);
        abortButton.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        sendButton.setText("Send");
    }

    private OnClickListener getAbortButtonListener(final Button replyButton, final Button replyButtonAbort, final EditText replyTextField, final EditText replyNameTextField) {
        System.out.println("getAbortButtonListener");
        OnClickListener abortListener = new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                restoreOriginalCommentComponentState();
            }

        };
        return abortListener;
    }

    private void restoreOriginalCommentComponentState() {
        System.out.println("restoreOriginalCommentComponentState");
        sendButton.setText(getOriginalButtonText());
        OnClickListener initialReplyButtonListener = getInitialButtonListener();
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(initialReplyButtonListener);

        abortButton.setVisibility(Button.GONE);
        textField.setText("");
        textField.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);
        nameTextField.setText("");
        nameTextField.setVisibility(EditText.GONE);
    }

    private OnClickListener getSendButtonClickedListener() {
        ...
        return sendCommentListener;
    }

    private Comment buildComment(final EditText replyTextField, final EditText replyNameTextField, final String commentID) {
        String commentText = replyTextField.getText().toString();
        Editable name = replyNameTextField.getText();
        Comment comment = new Comment(commentID);
        comment.setAuthor(name.toString());
        comment.setText(commentText);
        return comment;
    }

    protected abstract String getOriginalButtonText();

    protected abstract String getPartialUrl();

    protected abstract String getMessageToBeDisplayedOnSuccessfulSending();

    public LinearLayout getLinearLayout() {
        return currentLinearLayout;
    }

    public Button getSendButton() {
        return sendButton;
    }

    public void setText(final String text) {
//      ((Activity) context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
//
//          @Override
//          public void run() {
                textField.setText(text);
//          }
//      });
//This did not fix it
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        System.out.println("setting text: " + name);
        nameTextField.setText(name);
    }

    public Comment getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public EditText getTextField() {
        return textField;
    }

    public EditText getNameTextField() {
        return nameTextField;
    }
}
```

CommentCreationComponent

```
public class CommentCreationComponent extends BaseCommentComponent {

    public CommentCreationComponent(LinearLayout currentLinearLayout, Comment comment, Context context, Request request, Button sendButton,
            Button abortButton, EditText textField, EditText nameTextField) {
        super(currentLinearLayout, comment, context, request, sendButton, abortButton, textField, nameTextField);
        sendButton.setVisibility(Button.VISIBLE);
        sendButton.setText(getOriginalButtonText());
    }

    @Override
    protected String getOriginalButtonText() {
        return "New comment";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getPartialUrl() {
        return "publication/addComment";
    }

    @Override
    protected String getMessageToBeDisplayedOnSuccessfulSending() {
        return "Comment was sent";
    }

}
```

CommentSectionComponent

```
public class CommentSectionComponent {

    private LinearLayout placeHolder;
    private List<BaseCommentComponent> baseCommentComponents = new ArrayList<BaseCommentComponent>();

    public CommentSectionComponent(Context context) {
        Activity activity = (Activity) context;
        placeHolder = (LinearLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.placeHolder);
        TextView commentSectionHeader = new TextView(context);
        commentSectionHeader.setText("Kommentare");
        ComponentHelper.convertToHeaderLabel(commentSectionHeader, context);
        ComponentHelper.setPublicationDetailLayout(placeHolder);
        placeHolder.addView(commentSectionHeader);
    }

    public void addCommentComponent(BaseCommentComponent comment) {
        baseCommentComponents.add(comment);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = comment.getLinearLayout();
        placeHolder.addView(linearLayout);
    }

    public List<BaseCommentComponent> getBaseCommentComponents() {
        return baseCommentComponents;
    }
}
```

The strange thing is, that I can do something like this:
(in BaseCommentComponent)

```
private OnClickListener getInitialButtonListener() {
            System.out.println("getInitialButtonListener");
            OnClickListener replyButtonClickedListener = new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    openCommentForWriting();
                    sendButton.setOnClickListener(getSendButtonClickedListener());
                    textField.setText("yep");
                }

            };
            return replyButtonClickedListener;
        }
```

and it works when i click the button manually, but it doesn't work when i get the button into my Activity (just passing it up) and click it programmatically.
As you can see, i already tried some stuff without avail. I also checked the object-id's and they match (just to exclude accidentally overwriting the component somewhere)
I also already tried removing all the visibility-stuff to show the EditText-Fields from the get-go, obviously did not fix my problem.

Someone up for the challange? (Any help would be much appreciated)

Comment: Just because I try it sometimes, how about trying to call invalidate on the EditText after setting text?  Maybe on the UI thread as well.  I didn't read all the code as this is a really long post, so figured I'd throw that out there since you already tried running on UI thread.

Comment: Are you setting any `id`s to your components?

Comment: @wtsang02 : I downvoted because this is a very poorly structured question. The OP is supposedly trying to solve a problem with calling `setText(...)` on an `EditText` widget but has posted a load of unrelated code. The same question could have been asked in a much shorter post. If we want people to help us solve our coding problems we should keep things concise and in a way other people can reproduce the problem and (hopefully) provide a solution.

Comment: This code is ridiculous altogether. Its like something out of an enterprise nightmare. Please shorten this before we look to help.

Comment: wow... too much code? really? i thought you guys might ask for the xml to better reproduce my issue. I know that it's pretty heavy stuff I'm doing, thus I thought posting my structure would help you understand what i'm exactly doing. Didn't expect tl;dr responses though...

Comment: @user3207543 : The point of my comment is that you are more likely to get a helpful answer if you structure you question in a way that makes it easy for others to interpret. This does mean, unfortunately, tl;dr does apply for some questions. SO is designed to be a repository for questions and answers that others coming along later might search and find a solution to a coding problem. A particularly verbose question doesn't help anybody trying to help you and it won't help anyone searching for an answer to a similar problem.